# LLVM Liveness Analysis for SSA registers

Tags: clang, llvm, compiler-optimization, llvm-ir

I am trying to implement a pass that will answer queries like isAlive(var,n) where n is a basic block and var is any SSA variable. isAlive returns true if var is alive in the basic block n.

From what I have understood dominators and use-def chain should be enough to do this perhaps?

What I have in mind is:

let def(var) be the basic block that defines var. if def(var) dominates n (any other basic block) and n dominates at least one block that has a use of var. Then var is alive in n?

However, I am thinking of instructions that can clobber the memory for var (StoreInsts in LLVM) so then essentially I would have multiple def(var) blocks(?)

Will the algorithm then be if a single def(var) [from all the def(var) blocks] dominates n followed by n dominating any one block that has the use of var?

Any help on this will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A dominator tree will do that on its own. An SSA value is never clobbered; memory can be clobbered but an SSA value never is, SSA means single static assignment and clobbering is always some sort of second assignment.

Comment: I probably should mention *how* a dominator tree is enough. A Value v is alive in block x if any of these three conditions is true: ① v is defined in x ② v is used in x ③ the block in which v is defined dominates x and x either dominates or is postdominated by a block in which v is used. (Real use of this kind of thing usually has to consider phi nodes as well.)

Comment: Any resources on how to handle phi nodes?

Comment: Use of a phi node may be seen as use of the phi node's inputs. Or not, depending on the purpose of your function. It depends.

Comment: https://opensource.apple.com/source/llvmCore/llvmCore-2358.3/lib/Analysis/LiveValues.cpp.auto.html I believe this analysis does what you mentioned

Comment: One variant of it. Others are possible. As it says: "This uses a conservative approximation that errs on the side of returning false." For some use cases, the conservative approximation is to err on the side of returning true. It depends.